# Why static library cause alignment problems if the same shared library works ok?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, gcc, embedded

I have a very strange problem. I build two libraries from one software source: static (using ar) and dynamic (using gcc). After I link my test application with the dynamic library it works ok. But a test application linked with the static library exists with either "segmentation fault" or with "Unhandled fault: alignment exception ... illegal instruction".

Why? I know that there is a bug in my software code, but is there any difference in the memory alignment if a static library used?

Comment: It's hard to say. They're two differently compiled bits of code you're working with. It's probably an error in your code that just doesn't happen to manifest itself in one case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of static versus dynamic linking it should be clear that the memory layout is very different for the two binaries in question.

With static linking, *all* object code needed to satisfy the dependencies created in the linkers symbol table is included in the resulting binary.

With dynamic linking, these dependencies are rewritten into place holders that the loader tries to satisfy when the binary is loaded. The actual object code is loaded somewhere in memory according to the alignment requirements that exist for dynamic libraries.

Hence, the biggest difference lies in which object code is included in the binary. Something in your static library gets included that makes execution derail. I'd suggest doing some selective unit testing on your library code together with some code inspection to try to pinpoint the problem.